# retrieve text from <p> on landing page using ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I have to retrieve the text from the web page and put it on console.
I am not able to get the text from this html below. Can anyone please help me on this.

```
<div class="twelve columns">
<h1>Your product</h1>
<p>21598: DECLINE: Decline - Property Type not acceptable under this contract</p>
<div class="row">
</div>
```

I tried `b.div(:class => 'twelve columns').exist?` on irb and it says `true`.

I tried this - `b.div(:class => 'twelve columns').text`, and it returns me the text on the header not in paragraph.

I tried with - `b.div(:class => 'twelve columns').p.text`, it returned me `error - unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"p"}`

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing this on example you wrote worked for me:

```
browser.div(:class => 'twelve columns').p.text
```

Your best bet would be to check your page css for actually having provided elements structure, as well as that they are nested properly.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly fixed you HTML:

```
<div class="twelve columns">
<h1>Your product</h1>
<p>21598: DECLINE: Decline - Property Type not acceptable under this contract</p>
<div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Let's do a tiny example:

```
div = b.div(:class => 'twelve columns')
```

Enumeration of elements as follows:

```
div.elements.each do |e|
  p e
end
```

Will do something like that:

```
<Watir::HTMLElement ... # <h1>Your product</h1>
<Watir::HTMLElement ... # <p>21598: DECLINE: Decline - Property Type not acceptable under this contract</p>
<Watir::HTMLElement ... #<div class="row">
```

If you want to specify child element P from the DIV do this:

```
p = div.p
```

or

```
p = div.element( :tag_name => 'p' )
```

And when get text of P:

```
p.text # >> 21598: DECLINE: Decline - Property Type not acceptable under this contract
```

Or event do with your single string:

```
b.div(:class => 'twelve columns').p.text

=> "21598: DECLINE: Decline - Property Type not acceptable under this contract"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers Chelios & Majiora. I'll try to work on them and let you know if that works me

Comment: @user1344631 so what did you get?